# Nginx can't talk to PHP-fpm in Docker

Tags: php, nginx, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to create a docker environment for development of our PHP application. I'm using Docker Compose to configure the containers.

So far, things have mostly gone smoothly, but I am having trouble getting nginx talking to php-fpm.

```
2015/12/17 15:49:47 [error] 9#9: *5 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.99.1, server: , request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://172.17.0.9:9000", host: "mysite.docker.local:676"
```

Here is the relevant portion of my docker-compose.yml file:

```
app:
    image: yappabe/data
    volumes:
        - .:/var/www
        - /vendor
        - ./logs/nginx:/var/log/nginx
    tty: true

nginx:
    image: yappabe/nginx
    ports:
        - 676:80
    links:
        - php
    volumes_from:
        - app
    environment:
        DOCUMENT_ROOT: /var/www/public
        INDEX_FILE: index.php
        PHP_FPM_SOCKET: php:9000

php:
    image: yappabe/php:5.6
    volumes_from:
        - app
    links:
        - mysql
        - mailcatcher
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you got this config from [this](https://www.jverdeyen.be/docker/how-php-symfony-coreos-docker/) webpage, so I tried a subset of the setup you have.

It works fine for me with a stripped down test of your file.

```
app:
    image: yappabe/data
    tty: true

nginx:
    image: yappabe/nginx
    ports:
        - 676:80
    links:
        - php
    volumes_from:
        - app
    environment:
        DOCUMENT_ROOT: /var/www/app/web
        INDEX_FILE: index.php
        PHP_FPM_SOCKET: php:9000

php:
    image: yappabe/php
    volumes_from:
        - app
```

Comment: Thanks. I am still having the same issue though. When I attempt to load a php script I get a 502 HTTP response.

Comment: You should probably start with a working configuration, then modify it step-by-step, instead of working with a broken configuration and not knowing where to start. 502 probably means that your nginx config is incorrect, possibly.